# How do I rewrite Solr search results to show related entity reference field?

Tags: entities, search

1: I have two node types: "Plants", and "Pests". related using a field in the plants node type called "affecting_pests".

How do I modify the solr Search result view; in the case of a Pests result, to display " name of pest==>affected plant " in the results title, and instead of link to pest page, redirect to the parent plant that the pest affects?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the apachesolr module, implement [hook_apachesolr_search_result_alter()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_search_result_alter/7) in a custom module. The function you create will receive the $document object that you may modify. You will have to add logic in there to locate and load the appropriate related entity.